# 1D to 3D Array Conversion

Tags: python, numpy

Is there any efficient way to convert a 1D array like

```
[1,2,3]
```

to a 3D array like

```
[[(1,1),(1,2),(1,3)],
 [(2,1),(2,2),(2,3)],
 [(3,1),(3,2),(3,3)]]
```

in Numpy/Python?

Comment: y=[[(j,i) for i in x] for j in x] works. But I am assuming it is not efficient enough for your purposes?

Comment: Could you be more specific?  Nothing you've shown is an array -- you have a list, and then a list of lists of tuples -- and your output object would need to be a 3D array, not a 2D array, in numpy if the underlying elements are intended to be integers.

Comment: @AkshatHarit Thanks.

Comment: @DSM I am basically looking for sorted list of tuples. I have also edited the 3D thing. Thanks.

Comment: A.M.: I don't think you're following the difference between Python native types (which can contain different objects) and numpy's array type (which can't, not really).  On the bright side I think both @AkshatHarit's suggestion and the linked answer should give you what you need.

Comment: @DSM You are right. Both of them are very useful. Thanks :)